# How to save response from AT Command

Tags: android, at-command

I work on Android's application. I look for saving the responses from AT command.
For example when I execute this command:

```
  Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
  Process process = r.exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", "echo -e 'AT\r' > /dev/smd0"});
```

I would like to save the response which is

```
AT
OK
```

I can show this response by executing this command by the adb interface:

```
 # cat /dev/smd0
```

I found on the forums that I should make this code:

```
  Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process process = r.exec(new String[] {COMMAND TO EXECUTE });

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(  
                                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));  
                String line = null;  
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  

                    System.out.println(line);  
                }  
            } catch (IOException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }
```

When I replace COMMAND TO EXECUTE by "ls" for example, it work fine. But when I replace by "cat /dev/smd0" it show to me on LogCat Invalide id: cat /dev/smd0

Answer (score 1):

Good news, I think I have exactly the tool you are looking for: [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/). It will read a list of AT commands and provide the responses from the modem to stdout (or to a file). Example:

```
$ echo AT | atinout - /dev/ttyACM0 -
AT
OK
$
```

Or even

```
$ atinout - /dev/ttyACM0 - <<EOF
> AT+CSCS="UTF-8"
> AT+CPBS="ME"
> AT+CPBW=,"0123456789",129,"B. Endian"
> AT+CPBW=,"8967452301",129,"L. Endian"
> EOF

OK

OK

OK

OK
$
```

The input AT commands should just be normal text lines terminated with '\n', atinout will take care of terminating the command with '\r' when sending to the modem.

Comment: Well, I've successfully added this command to my custom Android by adding its source to AOSP build and compiling it in build time. When I log to the device via "adb shell" and then call "su" (I've rooted the device as well), it becomes a really challenge to discover which file in /dev I must send the AT lines...

Comment: You need to [compile it with a cross compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25059217/23118). As far as I know the tool chain to compile native binaries is called android-ndk as opposed to android-sdk which is for compiling java programs. That's all I know, I have never tried myself.