# Sending AT Commands in Android Using atinout library

Tags: android, c, unix, java-native-interface, at-command

As the question title suggest, I'm going to use atinout library in my android application to be able to send AT Commands to my device's gsm modem and get the response back.

I've searched the SO and other blogs and the best code I got is something like this, which does not cauese anything to be written to output :

```
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();

        Process process = r.exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", "echo -n -e 'AT\r' > /dev/smd0"});

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {

           output+= line ;
        }



        tv.setText(output);
```

**So my main concerns are :**

1- How to send a simple AT commmad (like AT Ok) to the device's gsm modem and "print" the response back ?

2- I have no idea how to use the atinout library in an android application project, since it is written in C language.

**By the way :**

I have successfully rooted my Sony Xperia M Dual (C2005) phone and have SuperUser installed on it, so this prerequisite is met.

Also, I think I need some fundamental training on Unix commands and Serial communication and I really love to learn any needed material.

**Finally,** I'm on a tight deadline ! So the more straightforward , the better!

**P.S. I don't want someone to write the code for me, I just need the guidelines.**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you please help how you get sorted out from this problem. I'm facing same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 0. Compile [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) for android and install it. For this I have no experience and cannot give any help other than some general guidelines that you need to replace `CC = gcc` in the Makefile with an appropriate cross compiler.

Step 1. Write all the AT commands you want to run into a file `input.txt` (using normal '\n' line endings, there is no need to mess with '\r' here).

Step 2. Change the exec line to

```
Process process = r.exec(new String[] {"su", "-c",
                                      "atinout input.txt /dev/smd0 output.txt"});
```

Wait for the process to finish execution (`process.waitFor()` I think).

Step 3. Open the file `output.txt` and read the output from this instead of process.getInputStream().

Comment: thanks, I followed your guide and I could make it work

Comment: Good news. Glad I could help.

Comment: Can I compile for android using [this android developer topic](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html)

Comment: Yes, using NDK should be the correct cross compiler for this.